# Not getting the Google places result properly

Tags: android, json, url, google-places

I am trying to get the result of Google places in json. but everytime i am getting teh result 
STATUS as REQUEST DENIED..

```
    package com.json.trial;


public class GetMethodEx {
    String API_KEY = "My Places Key";

    String baseUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    key="AIzaSyCQ6m78y0CLClpvldSwY-aI2JbbZGoFx68";
    double latitude,longitude;

    public String getInternetData()throws Exception{

        latitude=-33.8670522;
        longitude=151.1957362;

        GenericUrl reqUrl = new GenericUrl(baseUrl);

         reqUrl.put("location", Double.toString(latitude) + "," + Double.toString(longitude));
        reqUrl.put("radius", 500);
        reqUrl.put("types", "");
        reqUrl.put("sensor", "false");
        reqUrl.put("key", API_KEY);

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI (baseUrl);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l="";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while((l=in.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }finally{
            if(in!=null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried both for school and food type

Comment: I have tried this and its working https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=%22school%22&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCQ6m78y0CLClpvldSwY-aI2JbbZGoFx68

Comment: if you type directly the url withing in a single line for a particular latitude and longitude its working...But when am providing the url in above way..its just the null results and Status as REQUEST DENIED

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `reqUrl` in

```
URI website = new URI (baseUrl);
```

Try this:

```
URI website = new URI (reqUrl);
```

Comment: seeing the above code ..can u just tell me the way i am providing the latitude and longitude from CurrentLocation class to main class is fine or not..btw thanks for the reply...In the mean time i will try this and let u know..

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..i have done wat u told...but still no help. but i found my problem and solved it thanks

Comment: can you please share, what's your solution?